# Django REST: map 'update' to 'list' using CustomRouter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Problem explanation:**

There is a Django project using REST API. The router is defined as:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
```

The Accounts router:

```
router.register('accounts', AccountViewSet)
accounts_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'accounts')
```

There are other routers under `accounts_router` which use standard paradigm (as described on [Django Reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)), e.g.:

```
URL pattern: ^accounts/$ Name: 'account-list'
URL pattern: ^accounts/{pk}/$ Name: 'account-detail'
```

**Problem:**

Now there is object which has only 1 instance - `singleton_foo`. Showing its details view as `/accounts/foo_acc/singleton_foo/1` would be a bad idea, since user may expect #2, #3, etc.

**Goal:**

I want to use custom router to map '/accounts/foo_acc/singleton_foo/1' to '/accounts/foo_acc/singleton_foo'. Basically, I want to show and update `singleton_foo` details (*update*) in the list view (*list*)

I have tried using something like:

```
class SingletonNestedRouter(NestedSimpleRouter):
    routes = [
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/$',
            mapping={'get': 'list'},
            name='{basename}-list',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{pk}/$',
            mapping={'put': 'retrieve'},
            name='{basename}-retrieve',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Retrieve'}
        ),
    ]
```

And attach the router to accounts:

```
accounts_router.register('singleton_foo', SingletonFooViewSet, 'singletonfoo')
ConfigNestedRouter(domains_router, singleton_foo', lookup='singleton_foo')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is possible in your project, you can achieve same behavior by overriding some of a viewset's methods. The core things here:

- getting only first item in the queryset (with "[:1]" in get_queryset),
- deny creation of a new item if one is already exists (in create()),
- rewrite get_object() method so it won't raise exception when we haven't passed value for the lookup_field.

**views.py**

```
class SingletonView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = SingletonSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SingletonModel.objects.all()[:1]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.get_queryset().exists():
            return super(SingletonView, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return Response({
                'message': 'Already exists and can be only one!'
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        obj = shortcuts.get_object_or_404(queryset)

        # May raise a permission denied
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', SingletonView.as_view({'get':'list', 'post': 'create', 'delete': 'destroy', 'put': 'update'})),
]
```

Now you can access all methods (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) through the same url without pk with "only-one-item" control.

Comment: You answer looks good, but it doesn't work - it shows POST on the list page (no PUT). Wonder if it is even possible to do that in Django REST API.

Comment: @h3d0 What do you mean by "it shows POST on the list page (no PUT)"?

Comment: There is a Django REST GUI. When you navigate to the list-view url, it will have POST button (that will create new instance of the object). When you navigate to to details view, the buttons shown are PUT, DELETE. I need to have PUT shown in the list-level url - this is the goal.

Comment: @h3d0 As I understood from your task, there should be no list or detail view (and respectively - urls). So URL '/accounts/foo_acc/singleton_foo' should list your accounts (there would be only 1) and offer POST, PUT and DELETE methods. If you are using a router to build url config for your SingletonFooViewSet, router will split methods to many urls (usually one for list+post and one for detail+put+delete). To get all methods on one url, I've created urlpattern as it shown in my example in urls.py. Have you tried using it?

Comment: The whole project uses `DefaultRouter` as the base. Imagine there is a model in the database. But there will always be only 1 instance of the model - so there is no reason to show it like `/some_model/1` (because there will be no 2, 3, etc.). So I want to show this 1 instance on the `/some_model` and have detail-related action (PUT) and not list-related actions (LIST, POST).